# What does "I could use" mean?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, expressions

> "Can we have something to drink , here?"
>
> "I'll get you water"
>
> "I could really *use a drink.*"

What does "using drink" mean?

Comment: It's an American idiom. We rarely use it in the UK. *I could really use a pint of beer/a week's holiday/you name it.*

Comment: @WS2 : Thank you for that. But what does it mean ?

Comment: @WS2: It's not necessarily American, it is used in British English too.

Comment: @tchrist : To migrate this from here to ELL , is a moderator required or can I do that myself ? I did not see the migrating option so asked.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase, is an idiom and is informal in use. According the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could-use-sth),

> **used to say that you would like something**:
>
> Examples:
>
> - *I could use some help putting these decorations up if you're not too busy.*
> - *"Can I get you anything?" "Thanks. I could use a drink."*
>     ​
>
> **used to say that something or someone needs something**:
>
> Examples:
>
> - Their website could use an upgrade.
> - He could use a new suit for work.

In the phrase, *"I could really use a drink,"* the speaker means to say that he/she really wants to have a drink. You cannot say *"using drink"* for this purpose.

Note: This is applicable to both British and American English. Only that in AmE, it is not considered informal.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom. Here, it means the person needs or wants a drink (probably alcoholic beverages)

**Could use** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could-use)

> (also *could do with*)
>
> to need or want something
>
> *"I could use some help over here!"*
> *"You could do with a haircut."*